# Бесконечный вывод print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
pin_code = input('Создайте свой пин-код: ')
pin_len = len(pin_code)
len_while = True
while len_while:
    if pin_len == 4:
        print('a')
        len_while = False
    else:
        print('b')
```

Бесконечно выводится 'b', если выполняется условие else:

Comment: Понимаю что скорее всего ошибка тут ерунда, но я только учусь, поэтому так туплю

Comment: Какая ошибка? В этом коде так и записано, что должно бесконечно выводиться b, что не так?

Comment: @andreymal а как мне тога нужно сделать, чтобы выводилось не бесконечно, а цикл повторялся до тех пор, пока не будет выполнятся условие if

Comment: Сделайте что-нибудь, что изменит условие if. Сейчас внутри цикла нет никакого кода, который мог бы повлиять на if, а значит len_while всегда будет True и цикл всегда будет бесконечным

Comment: Перенесите `input` и вычисление `len` внутрь цикла

Comment: @CrazyElf да, все работает, но я не понимаю, почему так работает, а до этого не работало.

Answer (score 3):

Так можно, если я правильно понял:

```py
pin_code = None

while True:
    pin_code = input('Создайте свой пин-код: ')
    
    if len(pin_code) == 4:
        print('a')
        break
    else:
        print('b')

print(pin_code)
```

Comment: Да, все работает, но а почему до этого не работало как нужно, можете объяснить?

Comment: while len_while: любая длина больше 0, если pin_len не 4, код не достигает строки len_while = False, т.е. вечное else -> while len_while

Comment: У вас считывались данные с консоли 1 рас. Дальше заходило в цикл, где всегда срабатывал else. Тут же, каждый цикл, если не выходит запрашивает снова ввести данные.

Comment: Спасибо! Я всё понял.

Answer (score 2):

Добавь в конце else оператор break